# Array of Arrays - Print Names of Inner Arrays - Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have two arrays in one outer array

```
$array1 = @("a", "b")
$array2 = @("c", "d")
$arrayAll = $array1, $array2
```

I now want to print the names "array1" , "array2" in the foreach-loop

```
foreach($array in $arrayAll){
    Write-Host $array
}
```

Which returns

```
a b 
c d
with the result that i want would be
$array1
$array2
```

While $allArray.Count still returns 2 elements. How do i print just the Array names and not what is in the Arrays ?

Comment: A _hash table_ would make a lot of sense for this

Comment: That information is not stored in `$arrayAll`. Think of a variable like a bag or a purse. If you have two bags filled with marbles - one green bag, one blue bag - and you then empty both of them into a big **red** bag, then you don't have "a red bag of green-bag and blue-bag marbles" - you just have "a red bag of marbles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you expect but this is a good place for using a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables):

```
$hashAll = [ordered]@{}
$hashAll['array1'] = @("a", "b")
$hashAll['array2'] = @("c", "d")

foreach($key in $hashAll.Keys)
{
    "This is array: $key"
    $hashAll[$key]
}
```